# Iterating through and object property and putting the values inside variables in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to iterate through an object using the `for...in`  loop to get the values of all its properties and put them inside variables. I'm stumbling on this.

What I would like to do is loop through the object properties, put the `value` inside a variable of the same the name as the `property`  to use on them on another variable

```
somePromise.then(response => {  

  for (let property in response) {
    property = response[property]  // this doesn't work cause reuses the same variable
  }

  /// I take the value of each property from the loop and pass it down 
  user.updateInfoFromOldDB(
    userID,
    nguid,
    property1 
    property2,
    property3
    property4,
  )

  ...ommited_code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try Object.values()?

```
somePromise.then(response => {  

  const valuesArr = Object.values(response);

  /// I take the value of each property from the loop and pass it down 
  user.updateInfoFromOldDB(
    ...valuesArr
  )

  ...ommited_code
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly access the properties from the response:

```
somePromise.then(response => {  
  user.updateInfoFromOldDB(
    response.userID,
    response.nguid,
    response.property1,
    response.property2,
    response.property3
    response.property4,
  )
})
```

Comment: I cannot cause I get the following response `object is not iterable javascript`